# Reverse Polish Notation (AKA Postfix Notation) Calculator for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, calculator

I'm looking for a calculator application that supports [Reverse Polish Notation/Postfix Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) that runs on Windows 7.  I'd prefer an app that is portable or doesn't require admin rights to install, but I'll take what I can get.  I would also like to avoid having to dig around for calculator ROMS.

Comment: If you don't mind compiling it, [GRPN](http://lashwhip.com/grpn_download.html) is open-source and while aimed at unix, should work just fine on windows as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [RPNcalculator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rpncalcnet/):

- free and open source (BSD License)
- Windows
- Support RPN:

[image]

- if you need portability just copy the files CommonLib.dll, RPN_Calculator.exe and WPFToolkit.Extended.dll, no need to install.

Comment: I used 7-zip to extract the files from the exe archive.

Answer (score 2):

[Excalibur](http://www.freeware-guide.com/OldGoodFreeware/Excalibur.html) is a free RPN calculator that runs on Windows 7. It is portable. Just extract and run. The disadvantange is that it hasn't been updated since 2006, and the interface isn't very nice. I now use RPNcalculator shown in [Franck's answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/10820/6834), but I keep this around for the extended functionality

[image]